# Create links programmatically inside an EmberJS view

Tags: ember.js, view

I have a pretty complex view to render which involves some kind of recursion (the typical folder/file nested list). The fact that it contains heterogeneous objects (folders and files) make it even harder to write Handlebars templates.

Therefore, the only solution I've found is to create a view, and manually fill the render buffer. I came with the following solution:

```
App.LibraryContentList = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ol',
  classNames: ['project-list', 'dd-list'],

  nameChanged: function() {
    this.rerender();
  }.observes('content.@each.name'),

  render: function(buffer) {
    // We only start with depth of zero
    var content = this.get('content').filterProperty('depth', 0);

    content.forEach(function(item) {
      this.renderItem(buffer, item);
    }, this);
  },

  renderItem: function(buffer, item) {
    switch (item.constructor.toString()) {
      case 'App.Folder':
        this.renderFolder(buffer, item);
        break;
      case 'App.File':
        this.renderFile(buffer, item);
        break;
    }
  },

  renderFolder: function(buffer, folder) {
    buffer.push('<li class="folder dd-item">');
    buffer.push('<span class="dd-handle">' + folder.get('name') + '</span>');

    // Merge sub folders and files, and sort them by sort order
    var content = this.mergeAndSort();

    if (content.get('length') > 0) {
      buffer.push('<ol>');

      content.forEach(function(item) {
        this.renderItem(buffer, item);
      }, this);

      buffer.push('</ol>');
    }

    buffer.push('</li>');
  },

  renderFile: function(buffer, album) {
    buffer.push('<li class="album dd-item">');
    buffer.push('<span class="dd-handle">' + file.get('name') + '</span>');
    buffer.push('</li>');
  }
});
```

Now, what I'd like is to be able to add links so that each folder and each file is clickable and redirect to another route. But how am I supposed to do that, as I don't have access to the linkTo helper? I've tried to play with the LinkView view, but without any success. Should I register handlers manually for each item?

I've also thought about breaking that with a CollectionView instead, and splitting the content by depth so that I could render it using templates, but it seems more complicated.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just an idea which I didn't test, how about adding something like this `Ember.Handlebars.compile('<span>{{{link story}}}</span>')`

Comment: I thought about this, but I am only using the Handlebars runtime (I'm compiling my templates), so I'd like to avoid to introduce the dependency to the whole Handlebars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It occurs to me that the `linkTo` helper may not be the best way to approach this. All the `linkTo` does is `router.transitionTo`, dynamically resolving paths as needed plus the automatic `active` css property setup.

In your case, you already have the items list and hence the clicked item accessible within the View itself. So creating a `LinkView` dynamically or implicitly via the `{{#linkTo}}` helper to then handle the item that was clicked may not be necessary.

I would directly setup old-skool `data-some-id` on the generated item anchor. Then in the view handle the click, compute which item it corresponds to using `dataset.someId` and then `transitionToRoute` to that item, either directly in the view or via a `gotoItem` on the controller.

If there are many such items, this would have significant savings, on the number of DOM elements and Ember Views.

I tried this with a similar setup in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifiyap/2). I have used a `ProductsListView` with a template, but the approach would be similar with a programmatic `View` as in your example.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like the best solution :).

Comment: Is there another way to do this now with ember 1.5? I've encountered the same scenario, but am wondering if there is a more DRY way to do this.